# Selenium: how to get an array of all text visisble on page with same locator

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

I have the following locator on various parts of the webpage:(excerpt of HTML)

```
<table id="userPlaylistTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <p class="title"> ABC </p>
   <p class="title"> DEF </p>
   <p class="title"> GHI </p>
```

Now, all of the above have the exact same locators, so how do I get them all into a string something like: "ABC DEF GHI"

I would like to get this string, as this is a table and these are items arranged in a particular order in that table. If I re-arrange the order, then I would be able to verify that the reordering has taken place as the string obtained would change.

I tried

```
se.get_text("css=table#userPlaylistTable p.title")
```

But this gives me the text for only the first element i.e. "ABC"

Also, would there be any other way to get the order to the text in a table as mentioned above?

Could someone please help me with the above?
Thanks a lot.
Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RC then you try as mentioned below:

```
String s;
for(i=1;:i++)
{
String locator ="css=table#userPlaylistTable>p.title:nth("+i+")";
if(!selenium.isElementPresent(locator))
{
break;
}
String temp= selenium.getText(locator);
s.concat(temp);
}
```

In the above code I am iterating over the html code.If the locator is found I am getting the text and concatenating it with the String *s*. If the locator is not present I am coming out of the loop.